# Making loading screen

Tags: python

I got a error, any help?
I don't know why, here is the error: line 5 SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

```
print ("[+]                   0% ")
time.sleep(2)
print ("[+]-                 10% ")
time.sleep(2)
print ("[+]--                20% )
time.sleep(5)
print ("[+]----              50% ")
time.sleep(5)
print ("[+]-------           85% ")
time.sleep(2)
print ("[+]-----------       100%")
time.sleep(2)
print ("[+] Finished Successfull! ")
```

Comment: YOu are missing a " after 20%

Comment: @Chris     time.sleep(2)
NameError: name 'time' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `"` on the 5th line, it should be:

```
print ("[+]--                20%" )
```

Also, you haven't imported time. Add this line to the top of script:

```
import time
```

Comment: time.sleep(2)
NameError: name 'time' is not defined

Comment: You probably also need to `import time`